# Getting a glsl 330 context on osx 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl, glew, glfw

I saw a similar question here: [OpenGL 4.1(?) under Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865463/opengl-4-1-under-mavericks), but it seems that person is relying on glut, so the solution doesn't apply.

I'm on **OSX 10.9** *(Mavericks)*, with an **NVidia GeForce 650**, developing in **C++**, using **GLEW** and **GLFW**.

I'm **not** using xcode- keeping it simple with a very basic makefile.

Anyways- I have these 5 lines of code:

```
window = glfwCreateWindow(640,480,"hello world",NULL,NULL);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
glewInit();

printf("shader lang: %s\n",glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
```

and it prints out

```
shader lang: 1.2
```

I'm assuming setting glewExperimental should handle correctly getting the core context? (/ the stuff the other dude was talking about in the other thread)

**What else do I need to do to enable the latest shader versions?**

Ps- my full code is here, including the makefile: https://github.com/Phildo/openglexp , but I'm not sure how useful it will be.

Comment: What glfw window hints are you using? You need major version 3, minor version 2, core, forward compatible on OS X.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks so much! Out of curiosity- where/how did you find this information? I looked everywhere for it...

Comment: GLFW does not document this that I am aware of. I know this information because I work with the low-level OpenGL context management APIs (CGL / NSOpenGL) for my work. Apple documents it in various places, such as [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/opengl-macprogguide/opengl_pixelformats/opengl_pixelformats.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have never used GLFW before, but according to the API documentation and my thorough experience with low-level OS X GL context management, the following code should fix your problem:

```
glfwInit       ();

glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,        GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Make sure you call these things ***before*** `glfwCreateWindow (...)`

Comment: You also need the line `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);`. See http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compat.html#compat_osx

Comment: Oops. I must not have noticed it because of the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to get this to work - the above answers are correct. You need to add all of the aforementioned glfwWindowHints. However, this didn't immediately work for me UNTIL I moved the hints AFTER the call to glfwInit() and BEFORE glfwCreateWindow(). Thanks all for the help.