# GLSL version 130 on Mac OS X causes error

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glsl

I've been following through the code of the fifth edition of the OpenGL Superbible using Mac OS X, and have stumbled across a problem. In my vertex shader, I have included the version number, being `#version 130`. However, it fails to compile with the error `ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported`.

Info: I am using Xcode on Mac OS version 10.8.5, with an Intel HD Graphics 3000. It should support OpenGL version 3.0, which corresponds with GLSL version 1.30.

Comment: You will get, at a minimum, a 3.2 (core profile) context on 10.8 or a 3.3 context on Mavericks. i.e., GLSL 1.50 or 3.30.

Comment: @BrettHale any idea why it's giving me this error, then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you select a pixel format that ***explicitly*** asks for a core profile, then you are going to get an OpenGL 2.1 implementation. See my [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865463/opengl-4-1-under-mavericks/19868861#19868861) for more details on how to do this; this is a new change to the CGL / NSOpenGL APIs that was introduced with OS X 10.7, so some older books may not document it.

There is a big difference between what your GPU supports and what you actually get. On a lot of other platforms, without using changes to the window system APIs that were introduced alongside OpenGL 3.2, you can get all the features of an OpenGL 3.2+ implementation **and** the legacy things from OpenGL 2.1 and earlier **by default** (this is known as a compatibility profile).

OS X is different, it does not support compatibility profiles. You either get the legacy OpenGL 2.1 implementation or the core 3.2 (3.3/4.1 in OS X 10.9) implementation but you can never mix-and-match features from both. Furthermore, unless you modify your code to ask for a core profile, you will be limited to OpenGL 2.1 by default.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of that. As I am new to OpenGL, how would I go about setting the pixel format?

Comment: @Fitzy: How are you creating your render context? I imagine since you said you are new, you are not using the low-level APIs like CGL or NSOpenGL. If you are using something like GLUT, glfw3, SDL, etc. then they should each have a mechanism for requesting a core profile.

Comment: For now, I am using GLUT. It seems the code in the Superbible was not properly tested across all platforms- very disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS, the OpenGL version supported in linked to the system version.
The most advanced supported version is OpenGL 4.1 since OS X 10.9  (Mavericks).

Furthermore, OpenGL is now deprecated since macOS 10.14 (Mojave), you have to use the Metal framework or MoltenVK (a Vulkan wrapper for OS X).
Vulkan is the successor of OpenGL.

Useful links:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/604/

[Develop using OpenGL 4.x on OSX Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65802625/develop-using-opengl-4-x-on-osx-big-sur)