# Without moving to Metal, is there still a way existing OpenGL products can run on Mac?

Tags: macos, opengl, migration, compatibility, metal

I know, Apple has stopped supporting OpenGL to promote Metal, but I'm just curious to know if at all there are any alternatives present, that I can run OpenGL on Mac, without migrating my code to the Metal framework?

Like any 3rd party engines that I can make use of?

Comment: It's deprecated, but you can still use it, up to OpenGL 4.1 I believe

Comment: Question looks very close to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65802625/develop-using-opengl-4-x-on-osx-big-sur/65806319#65806319