# OpenGl and GLFW in a docker container

Tags: c++, docker, macos, opengl

I have a Mac(m1) which only has OpenGL 4.1 which does not support compute shaders, I want to try out raytracing but compute shaders don't work.

If I were to use a docker container to run my OpenGL program, could I use OpenGL 4.3 in the container or is Docker's OpenGL driver dependent on the host machine?

If I could use OpenGL 4.3, how would I be able to run a GLFW window in the container?  Would there be a way to see the GLFW window from my Mac?

Here is my Dockerfile and OpenGL code:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glfw/glfw3.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb/stb_image.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <filesystem>

#define GL_SHADER_FRAG 1
#define GL_SHADER_VERT 2

const char *LoadShader(std::string vertexPath, std::string fragmentPath, int type)
{
std::string vertexCode;
std::string fragmentCode;
std::ifstream vShaderFile;
std::ifstream fShaderFile;

vShaderFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
fShaderFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

try
{
    vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
    fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
    std::stringstream vShaderStream;
    std::stringstream fShaderStream;

    vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
    fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();

    vShaderFile.close();
    fShaderFile.close();

    vertexCode   = vShaderStream.str();
    fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
}
catch(std::ifstream::failure e)
{
    std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ. FILE: " << vertexPath << " " << fragmentPath << std::endl;
}
const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
const char* fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();

if(type == GL_SHADER_VERT).   
    return vShaderCode;
else if(type == GL_SHADER_FRAG)
    return fShaderCode;
}

int main()
{
glfwInit();

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL Raytracer", nullptr, nullptr);

if (window == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

std::cout << "OpenGL version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
const char* vertexShaderCode = LoadShader("/Users/nick/Programming/OpenGL-Raytracing/Vertex.glsl", "/Users/nick/Programming/OpenGL-Raytracing/Fragment.glsl", GL_SHADER_VERT);
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderCode, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertexShader);

unsigned int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
const char* fragmentShaderCode = LoadShader("/Users/nick/Programming/OpenGL-Raytracing/Vertex.glsl", "/Users/nick/Programming/OpenGL-Raytracing/Fragment.glsl", GL_SHADER_FRAG);
glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderCode, NULL);
glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

unsigned int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
glDeleteShader(vertexShader);

float vertices[] =
{
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f
};
unsigned int indices[] = 
{
    0, 1, 3,
    1, 2, 3
};
float texCoords[] = 
{
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 1.0f
};

unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

unsigned int texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true); 

int width, height, nrChannels;
unsigned char *data = stbi_load(std::filesystem::path("/Users/nick/Downloads/rtx1.png").c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
if (data)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}
stbi_image_free(data);

while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    int vertexColorLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "ourColor");
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUniform4f(vertexColorLocation, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}

glfwTerminate();
```

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

COPY ./ /usr/Nick/Maple

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y libglfw3-dev
RUN apt-get install -y cmake
RUN apt-get install -y make
RUN apt-get install -y clang
RUN apt-get install -y gobjc++
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y mesa-common-dev
RUN apt-get -y install xauth

RUN cd /usr/Nick/Maple && cmake .
RUN cd /usr/Nick/Maple && make

EXPOSE 8887
#RUN cd /usr/Nick/Maple/build/debug && ./OpenGL-Raytracing
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65802625/develop-using-opengl-4-x-on-osx-big-sur
In short: No, there is currently no way to get OpenGL >4.1 on MacOS. In fact, OpenGL has been deprecated by Apple and will be removed entirely in the future. Apple forces developers to use their own Metal API.

Comment: @JonathanS. 

If there's no way to run OpenGl 4.1+ on Mac, are there any tools/libraries that can transpile OpenGL to metal. I know MoltenVK does something like that for Vulkan, so would there be some thing like that to run OpenGL on metal

Comment: Such a library currently does not exist. There really is no way to get GL >4.1 on a Mac at the moment. The Mesa project is developing its own graphics driver for the Apple M1 right now; however, that driver is still far from complete and will only be usable if you install Linux on your M1 Macbook (once it's gotten to a usable state). You may have better luck using Vulkan via MoltenVK (or just use Apple's Metal API directly). In theory, running Mesa's Zink on MoltenVK on Metal might work, but I wouldn't bet on it as Zink is also still in early development.

Comment: So what you're saying is that is no way to run OpenGL 4.6+ on mac. One more question, is docker capabile of running OpenGL 4.3+, is Docker dependant on the drivers of the mac, or does it have some way to use it's own drivers.

Comment: Docker is dependent on the operating system you're running it on. It does not provide its own drivers.

Comment: What about a VM?

Comment: If you run a VM on your M1 Macbook, it does not have a graphics card and therefore no working OpenGL. Your Macbook simply doesn't have a graphics card in it that is (currently) compatible with GL 4.6, so there is no way to get GL 4.6 on this hardware. (Or anything above 4.1 for that matter.)

Comment: Alright thanks for the help, I was considering learning vulkan a while back, I think I'll try compute shaders/raytracing with that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly can't that's because OpenGL is not really a library that could be transferred from one place to another, it's integrated within the graphics processor, so you are kind of stuck with that version as far as I am aware, libraries like GLFW just help access the functions through api's. Although Vulkan works well with Macbooks